# Get hibernate SQL statistics for all executed SQLs

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to print the statistics for the SQLs executed by hibernate and I see that hibernate supports the if you set

```
hibernate.generate_statistics=true
```

I did that and when I am printing the statistics I am only seeing the native SQLs and HQLs that are executed in that session  but not the SQLs that are generated while loading the entities and their children.

Here is my code to log the statistics

```
    Statistics s = sessionFactory.getStatistics();
    s.logSummary();
    String[] queries = s.getQueries();
    System.out.println("Total Queries Executed ==>> " + queries.length);
    for(int i = 0; i < queries.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(queries[i]);
        long et = s.getQueryStatistics(queries[i]).getExecutionAvgTime();
        System.out.println("==>> Average Execution Time = " + et);

        et = s.getQueryStatistics(queries[i]).getExecutionMaxTime();
        System.out.println("==>> Max Execution Time  " + et);

        et = s.getQueryStatistics(queries[i]).getExecutionMinTime();
        System.out.println("==>> Min Execution Time  " + et);
    }
```

This prints only the HQLs or native SQLs but not the ones that are executed when loading the entities, like below

```
session.get(Employee.class, 123456L);
```

How can I get the statistics for the generated SQLs ?

Comment: You might have to change the log level to debug. Also, refer this link for more details https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/how-to-activate-hibernate-statistics-to-analyze-performance-issues/

Comment: its not the logging issue, if you look at the code , I am extracting the queries from statistics `s.getQueries();` and it returns only the native SQL or HQLs